# VideoJS v7.7.6 - player.qualityLevels() not working with VHS

Tags: javascript, video.js

Can anyone please advise how to use below quality levels in plain javascript file?

```js
let player = videojs('my-video');
let qualityLevels = player.qualityLevels();
```

Thanks

Comment: Refence url - https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-quality-levels.

Comment: There's an example of how to use it at the link you've provided

Comment: last time I checked VHS tapes didn't play in browsers

Comment: @misterben, But as described in the link, it is not working. Can you please share any working sample documentation. I have tried adding the library but it is not compatible with plain javascript file but it is compatible with nodejs as it is asking for source file of "video.js". Would be better if I can get working sample.